# How decrypt MD5

Tags: decrypt

I'm try decrypt one string in format MD5 but I have not been able, this the code:

```
String e = 'test@testcom';
Blob b = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(e));
System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b));
String result = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(b);
System.debug(result);
Blob b2 = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(result);
String e2 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b2);
```

Comment: **[MD5 is a one way hash function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1240852/1492485)**.

Comment: When you say "decrypt one string in format MD5" are you really trying to decrypt a provided hash, or find the hash generated by `Crypto.generateDigest`? Based on the code it seems like the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By it's very nature you cannot decrypt MD5. It's a one way hash algorithm. There are some sites that claim to decrypt certain phrases but all they do is store known phrases to return them.

[Reference](http://md5decrypt.net/en/)

> Md5 (Message Digest 5) is a cryptographic function that allows you to
>   make a 128-bits (32 caracters) "hash" from any string taken as input,
>   no matter the length (up to 2^64 bits). This function is irreversible,
>   you can't obtain the plaintext only from the hash. The only way to
>   decrypt your hash is to compare it with a database using our online
>   decrypter.

Comment: It's not encryption. It's a hash algorithm.